# How we can compare two strings without considering Double commas i.e " " , commas and Spaces in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

```js
if(Obj.firstname  != this.state.EverContact.firstName.value)
{
   this.state.CRMContact.infoIcon = 'fas fa-edit red';
}
```

Comment: you can trim the both values and then compare the values then trim() function won't allow spaces and the data you provided is not much clear

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please follow the guideline before asking your question on Stack Overflow.